# TS Lint warning message

Tags: angular, npm, lint, tslint

When I run `npm lint` command from Circle CI , I am getting following warning message.

```
Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration:
    templates-use-public
    no-access-missing-member
    invoke-injectable
    template-to-ng-template
Try upgrading TSLint and/or ensuring that you have all necessary custom rules installed.
If TSLint was recently upgraded, you may have old rules configured which need to be cleaned up.
```

Is it okay to clean up these rules or any new rules are there to serve the purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules may have been removed / replaced or shifted into tsconnfig. Check their documentation.

All of the above rules have been removed, you can [look at this thread.](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/260)